# Visual C++ 2005 and Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: visual-c++, windows-7

Can Visual C++ 2005 be run in Windows 7 64-bit? I tried installing it, and came up with some problems.

Comment: "and came up with some problems."  Perhaps you could elaborate.

Comment: Just to confirm, I use Windows 7 64-bit professional with VS C++ 2005 expression edition at work to make a 32-bit build of our app.  I don't think I had any issues.  And you ought to be more precise in what your problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various issues, so you may or may not be able to work with VS 2005 on Win7 (actually Vista introduced the incompatibilities for the most part) depending on what you want to do. Microsoft documents the limitations on a series of pages that start here:

[Visual Studio on Windows Vista and Windows 7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa948853.aspx)

> Visual Studio 2005 is supported on Windows 7 with the same limitations described in this article and the related pages. To use Visual Studio 2005 on Windows 7 you will need to install both Visual Studio 2005 Service Pack 1 and the Visual Studio 2005 Service Pack 1 Update for Windows Vista.

Note that a workaround I've heard suggested is running the affected version of Visual Studio in a virtual machine running WinXP.

Comment: +1 good answer. FYI I have done exactly this, I am running VS2005 on Win7 with no issues. I remember reading something about only being able to compile 32 bit apps, but I might be imagining that.